# How can I get a specific element of a set in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

Suppose we have the following code:

```
sets
i index of products /product_1, product_2/;

parameters
Inventory_Cost(i) /product_1 3, product_2 4/;
```

Now when I want to use `Inventory_Cost(3-i)` it gives me an error. `Inventory_Cost(3-ord(i))` doesn't work also. How should i correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what you want to do with this, but it should work like this:

```
sets
i index of products /product_1, product_2/;

parameters
Inventory_Cost(i) /product_1 3, product_2 4/
switchI(i);

switchI(i) =  Inventory_Cost(i+[card(i)-2*ord(i)+1]);

display switchI;
```